# Howto assign second ip to docker container with ip:port:port

Tags: networking, ip, docker, containers, coreos

I have a problem with docker and searched a couple of hours but cannot find a suitable answer for it. Let me explain: I have a VPS running CoreOS with 2 IPs on it. What I want is to assign one IP to the `container a` and the other IP to the `container b` using the `-p` option.

Well I have assigned one IP to a container but until now I cannot assign IP 2 to `container b` no matter what I try. I know you can use the option `-p IP:port:port` but when I do that I got the warning:

> Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 149.210.201.221:25: bind:
>   cannot assign requested address

When I setup a bridge with the IP I got the warning:

> the address is already in use.

What to do?

Comment: maybe there is already another service listening on that interface:port? What does `netstat -lnp` show?

Comment: Please check if the port for is free to use .You can check with `ps-ef | grep <port no.>`.....if it still persist try giving internal ip(local ip) of the server.

Comment: The port on the ip in my text is free. The other container is using that port of course, but on its own ip (149.210.201.201)